# Can we determine if a router is changing its position? E.g. a router inside of a bus, train etc

Tags: swift, networking, router

I would like to know if it is possible somehow do determine if a router is changing its position. I need to know that because I am writing a mobile application that is gonna be working on WiFi networks(connects people on the same network / connected to the same router). I know that the mobile device can explore the network (e.g. getting the WiFi SSID). I was wondering if it is possible to know somehow if the router changed its position. I want to connect the people only if they are connected to the same router which is changing its position from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single device to perform the detection, you are limited to detecting the connection latency as an estimate of distance, though this is probably sufficient. You can probably improve this by detecting if you are also moving.

If you have multiple devices or multiple receivers on a single device, you can do this much better through [tri/multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) of the router by combining several distance estimates.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, maybe above 90% of the routers are static. They are situated somewhere and they barely change their position. It could happen if you accidentally kick it or something and it moves few centimetres away. In theory, I could determine if 2 people are on the same SSID and I could group them. But, how can I say that they are both connected to a moving router? I am curious based on what we say it is moving? IP change, some location property or what?